# Changing legend labels in ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, labeling, legend, layouts

I don't know how to change legend labels using attribute table. I want to use values from "litologia" field instead of "kod".

Is this even possible or do i have to switch value field in symbology properties and create all symbols again?

[image]

Comment: If you just want to change the heading then click on "kod" in table of contents twice (slower than doubleclick) and type a new name

Comment: Thanks, but i need it to display all values from "litologia" field as legend labels (e.g. 
"namuły" instead of "nQh")

Comment: Just change the field to litologia under the symbology tab for layer property. If you want to keep the original symbols then you need to change the labels, this too is under the symbology tab. Read the help file [here](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/map/working-with-layers/drawing-a-layer-using-categories.htm).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use values from "litologia" field instead of "kod" in your legend, one workaround is to add the layer a second time to your mxd.  Set the second layer's symbology to the "litologia" field, and display this [second] layer in your legend.

You can have layers in your legend that are not turned on in the table of contents, just make sure to uncheck the box labeled "Only display layers that are checked on in the Table of Contents."
[image]